# How can I transfer data from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, database, transfer

I have two tables called `Top` and `Mid` that have the same structure in MySQL.

I would like to transfer the data in Top table to Mid table through *AdminPage*.

There will be a select box on *AdminPage* that has two options `<top, mid>`

And I want the data to be transferred according to the option I select.

How can I make a query like that?

Comment: You can make this clearer by stating the "options" in transferring the data

Comment: What admin page would that be? Is there a product called mysql_how?

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing. When user will select the checkboxes, you have to store the ids of those rows. Then run the below query

```
Insert into Mid (Column1,Column2)
Select Column1, Column2 from Top where id in (1,2,3,9..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `Mid`
SELECT * FROM `Top`
-- Critera Below
WHERE [column] = [value]
```